# How do I configure wireless VLANs on DD-WRT such that different wireless devices are in separate VLANs, e.g. salesVLAN, supportVLAN, etc.?

Tags: wifi, vlan, subnet, openwrt, wireless-bridge

I have a wireless AP running **dd-wrt**.
I have mobile phones, tablets, laptops, a printer and a scanner that all connect to the Wifi.

Is it possible to apply **VLANs** to the wireless AP such that *different devices* associate with *separate VLANs*?

**Here is an example Layer 2 diagram:**
[image]

Lets say in the above scenario I wanted the devices to be on the following separate VLANs:

1. GREEN: 192.168.1.0/24
2. BLUE: 192.168.2.0/24
3. YELLOW: 192.168.3.0/24
4. PURPLE: 192.168.4.0/24
5. RED: 192.168.5.0/24

**Questions:**

1. How can I achieve this?
2. Does this require separate SSIDs per VLAN?

*(Apologies if this is not the correct Stack Site.)*

Comment: You need different SSID, most router will do it that way

Comment: I suspected that would be the case...and it makes sense.